# Cannot read database

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

i'm trying to read from my database but I get these errors. My db is in the assets folder. I've downloaded the AnyDBAdapter class and just trying to use a simple select function..

```
02-18 14:18:24.168: E/SQLiteLog(964): (14) cannot open file at line 30176 of [00bb9c9ce4]
02-18 14:18:24.168: E/SQLiteLog(964): (14) os_unix.c:30176: (2) open(/data/data/com.onlywithalcohol.mk/databases/Alcohol_DB) - 
02-18 14:18:24.387: E/SQLiteDatabase(964): Failed to open database '/data/data/com.onlywithalcohol.mk/databases/Alcohol_DB'.
02-18 14:18:24.387: E/SQLiteDatabase(964): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14): Could not open database
02-18 14:18:24.387: E/SQLiteDatabase(964):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeOpen(Native Method)
02-18 14:18:24.387: E/SQLiteDatabase(964):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:209)
02-18 14:18:24.387: E/SQLiteDatabase(964):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:193)
02-18 14:18:24.387: E/SQLiteDatabase(964):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.openConnectionLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:463)
02-18 14:18:24.387: E/SQLiteDatabase(964):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:185)
02-18 14:18:24.387: E/SQLiteDatabase(964):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:177)
02-18 14:18:24.387: E/SQLiteDatabase(964):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openInner(SQLiteDatabase.java:804)
02-18 14:18:24.387: E/SQLiteDatabase(964):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.open(SQLiteDatabase.java:789)
02-18 14:18:24.387: E/SQLiteDatabase(964):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:694)
02-18 14:18:24.387: E/SQLiteDatabase(964):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:669)
02-18 14:18:24.387: E/SQLiteDatabase(964):  at com.onlywithalcohol.mk.AnyDBAdapter$DatabaseHelper.checkDataBase(AnyDBAdapter.java:150)
02-18 14:18:24.387: E/SQLiteDatabase(964):  at com.onlywithalcohol.mk.AnyDBAdapter$DatabaseHelper.createDataBase(AnyDBAdapter.java:119)
02-18 14:18:24.387: E/SQLiteDatabase(964):  at com.onlywithalcohol.mk.AnyDBAdapter.open(AnyDBAdapter.java:47)
02-18 14:18:24.387: E/SQLiteDatabase(964):  at com.onlywithalcohol.mk.Main$1.onClick(Main.java:30)
02-18 14:18:24.387: E/SQLiteDatabase(964):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4202)
02-18 14:18:24.387: E/SQLiteDatabase(964):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17340)
02-18 14:18:24.387: E/SQLiteDatabase(964):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
02-18 14:18:24.387: E/SQLiteDatabase(964):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-18 14:18:24.387: E/SQLiteDatabase(964):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-18 14:18:24.387: E/SQLiteDatabase(964):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
02-18 14:18:24.387: E/SQLiteDatabase(964):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-18 14:18:24.387: E/SQLiteDatabase(964):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-18 14:18:24.387: E/SQLiteDatabase(964):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
02-18 14:18:24.387: E/SQLiteDatabase(964):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
02-18 14:18:24.387: E/SQLiteDatabase(964):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-18 14:18:24.648: D/AndroidRuntime(964): Shutting down VM
02-18 14:18:24.648: W/dalvikvm(964): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a70930)
02-18 14:18:24.748: E/AndroidRuntime(964): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-18 14:18:24.748: E/AndroidRuntime(964): java.lang.Error: Error copying database
02-18 14:18:24.748: E/AndroidRuntime(964):  at com.onlywithalcohol.mk.AnyDBAdapter$DatabaseHelper.createDataBase(AnyDBAdapter.java:135)
02-18 14:18:24.748: E/AndroidRuntime(964):  at com.onlywithalcohol.mk.AnyDBAdapter.open(AnyDBAdapter.java:47)
02-18 14:18:24.748: E/AndroidRuntime(964):  at com.onlywithalcohol.mk.Main$1.onClick(Main.java:30)
02-18 14:18:24.748: E/AndroidRuntime(964):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4202)
02-18 14:18:24.748: E/AndroidRuntime(964):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17340)
02-18 14:18:24.748: E/AndroidRuntime(964):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
02-18 14:18:24.748: E/AndroidRuntime(964):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-18 14:18:24.748: E/AndroidRuntime(964):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-18 14:18:24.748: E/AndroidRuntime(964):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
02-18 14:18:24.748: E/AndroidRuntime(964):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-18 14:18:24.748: E/AndroidRuntime(964):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-18 14:18:24.748: E/AndroidRuntime(964):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
02-18 14:18:24.748: E/AndroidRuntime(964):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
02-18 14:18:24.748: E/AndroidRuntime(964):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here is my AnyDBAdapter class:

```
package com.onlywithalcohol.mk;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.UUID;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class AnyDBAdapter {

    private static final String TAG = "AnyDBAdapter";
    private DatabaseHelper mDbHelper;
    private static SQLiteDatabase mDb;

    //make sure this matches the 
    //package com.MyPackage;
    //at the top of this file
    private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.onlywithalcohol.mk/databases/";

    //make sure this matches your database name in your assets folder
    // my database file does not have an extension on it 
    // if yours does
    // add the extention
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Alcohol_DB";

    //Im using an sqlite3 database, I have no clue if this makes a difference or not
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 3;

    private final Context adapterContext;

    public AnyDBAdapter(Context context) {
        this.adapterContext = context;
    }

    public AnyDBAdapter open() throws SQLException {
        mDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(adapterContext);

        try {
            mDbHelper.createDataBase();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            throw new Error("Unable to create database");
        }

        try {
            mDbHelper.openDataBase();
        } catch (SQLException sqle) {
            throw sqle;
        }
        return this;
    }

    public Cursor selectRecord(int id){
        Cursor c = mDb.rawQuery("SELECT title FROM alcorecords"
                + " WHERE id ='"+id+"'", null);
                   return c;
    }
    //Usage from outside
    // AnyDBAdapter dba = new AnyDBAdapter(contextObject); //in my case contextObject is a Map
    // dba.open();
    // Cursor c = dba.ExampleSelect("Rawr!");
    // contextObject.startManagingCursor(c);
    // String s1 = "", s2 = "";
    // if(c.moveToFirst())
    // do {
    //  s1 = c.getString(0);
    //  s2 = c.getString(1);
    //  } while (c.moveToNext());
    // dba.close();
    public Cursor ExampleSelect(String myVariable)
    {
        String query = "SELECT locale, ? FROM android_metadata";
        return mDb.rawQuery(query, new String[]{myVariable});
    }

    //Usage
    // AnyDBAdatper dba = new AnyDBAdapter(contextObjecT);
    // dba.open();
    // dba.ExampleCommand("en-CA", "en-GB");
    // dba.close();
    public void ExampleCommand(String myVariable1, String myVariable2)
    {
        String command = "INSERT INTO android_metadata (locale) SELECT ? UNION ALL SELECT ?";
        mDb.execSQL(command, new String[]{ myVariable1, myVariable2});
    }

    public void close() {
        mDbHelper.close();
    }

    private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        Context helperContext;

        DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
            helperContext = context;
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database!!!!!");
            //db.execSQL("");
            onCreate(db);
        }

        public void createDataBase() throws IOException {
            boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();
            if (dbExist) {
            } else {

                //make sure your database has this table already created in it
                //this does not actually work here
                /*
                 * db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS \"android_metadata\" (\"locale\" TEXT DEFAULT 'en_US')"
                 * );
                 * db.execSQL("INSERT INTO \"android_metadata\" VALUES ('en_US')"
                 * );
                 */
                this.getReadableDatabase();
                try {
                    copyDataBase();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    throw new Error("Error copying database");
                }
            }
        }

        public SQLiteDatabase getDatabase() {
            String myPath = DB_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
            return SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,
                    SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
        }

        private boolean checkDataBase() {
            SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;
            try {
                String myPath = DB_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
                checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,
                        SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
            } catch (SQLiteException e) {
            }
            if (checkDB != null) {
                checkDB.close();
            }
            return checkDB != null ? true : false;
        }

        private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {

            // Open your local db as the input stream
            InputStream myInput = helperContext.getAssets().open(DATABASE_NAME);

            // Path to the just created empty db
            String outFileName = DB_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;

            // Open the empty db as the output stream
            OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

            // transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int length;
            while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }

            // Close the streams
            myOutput.flush();
            myOutput.close();
            myInput.close();
        }

        public void openDataBase() throws SQLException {
            // Open the database
            String myPath = DB_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
            mDb = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,
                    SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
        }

        @Override
        public synchronized void close() {

            if (mDb != null)
                mDb.close();

            super.close();

        }
    }

}
```

And all I'm trying to do is this:

```
AnyDBAdapter adapter = new AnyDBAdapter(getApplicationContext());
                adapter.open();
                adapter.selectRecord(num);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this your db path,

```
private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.onlywithalcohol.mk/databases/";
```

if not then change it ,to your db name.

Comment: somehow from com.alcotest.mk my package was renamed to com.example.alcotest that was theh problem